# E-shopping, the store refunds less money, how act?

Tags: debit-card, online-payment, refund, online-shopping

I've ordered some product online. The next day I got an email:

> On 1st time orders, our company requires transactions to be completed
>   via Paypal. We have refunded your credit card for the total amount of
>   the order.

But I've got about 2$ less, than I paid. The company support says that

> PayPal does impose a fee for this service

But that looks like I've paid just for nothing. Doesn't that violates some law? Would it be possible for me to return the whole sum?

The purchase has been made online through debit MasterCard. It is not virtual.

P.S. Should I write the name of the store here?

Comment: I doubt you have any reasonable way to get your $2 back, certainly no way that is worth pursuing just for $2.  Charging fees for processing refunds is quite common.  In some cases it's a lot more than $2, so I think you actually got off pretty well.  It's only $2.  Just live with it.

Comment: For clarification - let's say the initial purchase was $3. You made that purchase with your credit card directly (no PayPal account.) The company "refunded" your order, but only gave you $1 back directly to your credit card?

Comment: @Todd, yes. It may be not exactly 2$, but roughly it is.

Comment: What was the total amount of the charge?  $2 sounds like a lot of money, but if this is buying a car or something it is perhaps not.

Comment: @cheetahfm Assuming you don't care to ever do business with this company in the future, the best way to get all your money back would be to call up your bank and dispute the transaction. Tell them that the company cancelled the order and didn't completely refund you. Informing the company of this intended action may goose them to give you the rest of the money back, because the chargeback's going to cost them more than the $2. Note - this is assuming your PayPal account has nothing to do with this transaction, since chargebacks and PayPal can lead to bad things.

Comment: Was a foreign currency conversion involved?

Comment: Shame them.  If they have a Facebook or Twitter account and you do too, ask them publicly why they make it hard and expensive to be a first-time buyer.

Comment: @Joe, the total sum is 37.65. It is a flashlight with batteries.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea, yes, but the company support gave me the transaction details, which show that the fee was charged in $, so it was before conversion.

Comment: @user662852, I've asked the company support, why didn't they just block all the other methods for first-time buyers. They said, that it was impossible, "since there is not an applicable screening process in the checkout screen to determine if it is a first time order or not". Looked rather stupid to me, cause I've created my account specifically to buy, so checking number of purchases for the account should not be difficult.

Comment: Violate law; probably not. Did you read through their Terms of Service before finalizing the online order? For the sake of curiosity, what was this online store?

Comment: @Todd, what are the bad things? What if the very same card is added to my PayPal account?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, [fenixoutfitters](https://www.fenixoutfitters.com)

Comment: Does this apply to you? "[Your refund will be the purchase price LESS the initial shipping cost.](http://www.fenix-store.com/warranty-info/#Five)"

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, don't think so. 1. The order was refunded by the store. 2. The order was refunded way before the shipping.

Comment: In that case I would dig deeper into their Terms of Service. If they cannot justify their actions within their ToS and cannot point you to text which states the PayPal shenanigans then you can certainly use that as leverage. It shouldn't be your fault that this is how they choose to conduct business.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your simplest option, and probably the only reasonable one, is to dispute the original charge with your bank.  Since you used a debit card and not a credit card, you don't have quite as much protection, but you still can dispute the charge and ask your bank to step in and help.  See [this debit card dispute article](http://www.creditcards.com/credit-card-news/how-dispute-debit-card-transaction-purchase-1282.php) for more information on disputing a charge for a debit card.

You may or may not have a case here, depending on the specifics.  If the merchant accepted your payment without letting you know you should have used paypal, you may have a shot at getting the full refund; but if it was clearly labelled that you should have used paypal, it may be harder.

Comment: This answer may be US specific, fyi - I don't know if 'dispute' is an option in other countries.

Comment: The purchase has been made in US online store from Russia, so I don't know if it's applicable, but I'll try, thanks.

Comment: @cheetahfm if the currency was ever converted the $2 short likely represents a currency fluctuation between the time you paid and the time the funds were refunded.